# Not accepting password regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I added a password regex to my user password in `User` model code as below.

```
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
validate :password_complexity
has_secure_password

def password_complexity
  if password.present? and not password.match(/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d). /)
    errors.add :password, "must include at least one lowercase letter, one uppercase letter, and one digit"
  end
end
```

When I tried `Password1`, it won't accept it. Any ideas why this won't take?

Comment: Remove space in the end of the regexp: `/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?
        =.*\d).|-- here --|/`

Comment: In cases like this, https://regex101.com/ is your friend.

Comment: I suggest you to not use this stuff at all. You see, you add additional overhead to your Rails app just that some people can't use their password of choice. It always annoys me when websites tell me what kind of password to use. You will most likely hash the password on the backend side, so there is no point to use this rule at all.

Comment: @praszyk, I agree with you, can't stand password restrictions, but this is a requirement for the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that using a single Regexp, even if possible, might be less effective as far as performance and handling goes.

Also, using `String#match` is slower than using `String#=~` because of the different return values.

I would separate the requirements into a number or Regexp and keep it a bit simpler, like this:

```
def password_complexity
  return unless password.present?
  unless password =~ /[a-z]/ && password =~ /[A-Z]/ && password =~ /[\d]/
    errors.add :password, "must include at least one lowercase letter, one uppercase letter, and one digit"
  end
end
```

It's a bit simpler to read and maintain. It also allows you to break the error messages to down to more specific errors later on, maybe like so:

```
def password_complexity
  return unless password.present?
  errors.add :password, "must include at least one lower case letter." unless password =~ /[a-z]/
  errors.add :password, "must include at least one upper case letter."  unless password =~ /[A-Z]/
  errors.add :password, "must include at least one digit." unless password =~ /[\d]/
end
```

Comment: This works perfectly, THANK YOU @Myst!!!!  Didn't realize I could separate the regex into various parts.  Big help and learning moment for me -- thanks.  :)

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of this pattern

```
if password.present? and not password.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+\d+/)
```

See this [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gD8wO2/1)

Hope this helps.

Comment: OP's regex is not that complex. There is need for a look ahead. The OP's use of it is fine. Your regex is neither sufficient nor necessary.

Comment: So can you explain why it didn't mach password1

Comment: See  dimakura's comment. By the way, `Password1`, not `password1`. The latter is supposed to be rejected.